# Inequalities between distances in $ \Bbb R^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I have to prove the following:

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\Bbb C$.Then $∣d(z,A)-d(w,A)∣ \le ∣z-w∣$, for all $z,w \in\Bbb C$.

And this is my attempt:

Let $z,w \in  \Bbb C$.
If $z,w$ are in $A$ then $0 \le ∣z-w∣$.

If $z,w$ are not in $A$ then $d(z,A)\neq0$ and $d(w,A)\neq0$.

$\implies \exists \mathcal E>0:\forall x\in A, d(z,x)\ge\mathcal E$ and
$\exists \mathcal E_2>0:\forall y\in A, d(w,y)\ge\mathcal E_2$.

..and then I don't know how to continue, maybe I should use triangle inequality? But how?

Help please.

Comment: "If z,w are not in A then d(z,A)≠0 and d(w,A)≠0" is false. Consider A to be the irrational numbers, and let z, w be rational numbers. Then d(z, A) = d(w, A) = 0.

Comment: I don't see it clearly @VictorChavauty. I think I'm gonna need a more detailed proof :(

Comment: @AaronMartinez in general if $A$ is open, you can have null distance to $A$ but not belong to $A$, when the point is right at the boundary. For instance if $A$ is the interior of a disk, points on the boundary (the circle bounding the disk) have $0$ distance to $A$ but do not belong to $A$

Comment: @AaronMartinez on a side note, if you want your proof to be fully rigorous, you need to address the case when $z\in A$ but $w\notin A$

Comment: So should I modified @MartinArgerami proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $a\in A$. Then 
$$
d(z,A)\leq |z-a|\leq|z-w|+|w-a|.
$$
So $d(z,A)-|z-w|\leq |w-a|$ for all $a\in A$, and then $$d(z,A)-|z-w|\leq d(w,A).$$
Thus
$$
d(z,A)-d(w,A)\leq|z-w|.
$$
As the roles of $z$ and $w$ can be exchanged, we also get 
$$
d(w,A)-d(z,A)\leq|z-w|.
$$
Thus
$$
|d(z,A)-d(w,A)|\leq|z-w|.
$$

Comment: why can you pass from line 3 to 4? (line 1 is Fix a..)

Comment: Because $d(w,A)$ is the infimum of $|w-a|$ over all $a\in A$. So $d(w,A)\leq |w-a|$.

Comment: right :) thanks